# Why Join fetch or Entity Graph generate n+1 with many to many relation?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

I'm trying to use entity graph with some data and I'm running into n+1 query

I created new project with spring boot 2.2.6 with some tables.

As I understood, using Fetch or Entity Graph should generate only one query

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String address;

    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Level level;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Department department;


    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Formations> formations = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", address='" + address + '\'' +
                ", dateOfBirth=" + dateOfBirth +
                ", level=" + level +
                ", formations=" + formations +
                '}';
    }
```

2. Formations entity

   ```
    @Entity
    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @ToString(exclude = "students")
    public class Formations {
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
       private Long id;    
       private String name;    
       @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "formations")
       @JsonIgnore
       private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>();
       public Formations(String name) {
           this.name = name;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Student Repository

   ```
    @Repository
    public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long>, 
    CustomStudentRepository {
    @Query("SELECT s FROM Student s  " +
           " join fetch s.level l " +
           " join fetch s.department d " +
           " join fetch s.formations f " +
           "  where s.id =:id ")
    Student fetchWithFormations(@Param("id") Long id);}
   ```
4. My Custom repository implemetation

   ```
   public class StudentRepositoryImpl implements CustomStudentRepository {

   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager em;

   private static final String QUERY = " SELECT s FROM Student s join fetch s.formations  where s.id =:id ";

   public Student findStudentByEntityGraph(Long id) {
       EntityGraph<Student> graph = this.em.createEntityGraph(Student.class);
       graph.addAttributeNodes("department", "level", "formations");

       return em.createQuery(QUERY, Student.class)
               .setParameter("id", id)
               .setHint("javax.persistence.loadgraph", graph)
               .getSingleResult();
   }


   public Student findStudentByFetch(Long id) {
       return em.createQuery(QUERY, Student.class).setParameter("id", id).getSingleResult();
   }
   ```

   }

The findStudentByFetch and the findStudentByEntityGraph generate 04 queries

```
// Generated Queries, I have 1 student with id 15 associated with 03 formations

Hibernate: select student0_.id as id1_3_0_, formations2_.id as id1_1_1_, department3_.id as id1_0_2_, level4_.id as id1_2_3_, student0_.address as address2_3_0_, student0_.date_of_birth as date_of_3_3_0_, student0_.department as departme6_3_0_, student0_.first_name as first_na4_3_0_, student0_.last_name as last_nam5_3_0_, student0_.level as level7_3_0_, formations2_.name as name2_1_1_, formations1_.students as students1_4_0__, formations1_.formations as formatio2_4_0__, department3_.name as name2_0_2_, level4_.name as name2_2_3_ from student student0_ inner join student_formations formations1_ on student0_.id=formations1_.students inner join formations formations2_ on formations1_.formations=formations2_.id left outer join department department3_ on student0_.department=department3_.id left outer join level level4_ on student0_.level=level4_.id where student0_.id=?
Hibernate: select students0_.formations as formatio2_4_0_, students0_.students as students1_4_0_, student1_.id as id1_3_1_, student1_.address as address2_3_1_, student1_.date_of_birth as date_of_3_3_1_, student1_.department as departme6_3_1_, student1_.first_name as first_na4_3_1_, student1_.last_name as last_nam5_3_1_, student1_.level as level7_3_1_ from student_formations students0_ inner join student student1_ on students0_.students=student1_.id where students0_.formations=?
Hibernate: select students0_.formations as formatio2_4_0_, students0_.students as students1_4_0_, student1_.id as id1_3_1_, student1_.address as address2_3_1_, student1_.date_of_birth as date_of_3_3_1_, student1_.department as departme6_3_1_, student1_.first_name as first_na4_3_1_, student1_.last_name as last_nam5_3_1_, student1_.level as level7_3_1_ from student_formations students0_ inner join student student1_ on students0_.students=student1_.id where students0_.formations=?
Hibernate: select students0_.formations as formatio2_4_0_, students0_.students as students1_4_0_, student1_.id as id1_3_1_, student1_.address as address2_3_1_, student1_.date_of_birth as date_of_3_3_1_, student1_.department as departme6_3_1_, student1_.first_name as first_na4_3_1_, student1_.last_name as last_nam5_3_1_, student1_.level as level7_3_1_ from student_formations students0_ inner join student student1_ on students0_.students=student1_.id where students0_.formations=?
```

If I remove formations from addAttributeNodes and from Query, it generate one query as expected

Need help please

Comment: Please also post the generated queries. You can write them to the console with `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` in your `application.properties`.

Comment: You are serializing student - that will init lazy relations.

Comment: Does it help if you add `join fetch f.students` to your join-fetch query?

Comment: @Antoniossss, I thought that all relations fetching mode are override at runtime using JOIN FETCH.

Comment: @DarioSeidl No, it throw an error. So I wonder why adding f.student in this case. As you can see my root query is Student.

Comment: Maybe it's because of the `@Data` on the Formations entity?
I suppose it's wrong to use @Data - any call for equals or hashCode will initialize lazy collection.